# Merging 2 vectors of different lengths and sorting them beforehand WITHOUT the sort function

Tags: c++, sorting

Here is my code so far. Everything works but the sorting and merging. How can I write this so that it sorts before merging without the use of the sort function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector < string > que1;
    vector < string > que2;
    vector < string > queMerge;
    string input;

    cout << "Enter queues" << endl;
    while(input != "ENDQ"){ //This while loop fills up the first vector with the values until the first "ENDQ" is reached
        cin >> input;
        que1.push_back(input);
    }
    que1.pop_back();//This statement removes the "ENDQ" input from the vector changing the vector size to 1 less

    input = ""; //Sets input to nothing so that it can loop through the second while loop for the second queue
    while(input != "ENDQ"){//This while loop fills up the second vector with the values until the first "ENDQ" is reached
        cin >> input;
        que2.push_back(input);
    }
    que2.pop_back();//This statement removes the "ENDQ" input from the vector changing the vector size to 1 less
```

Here is where I start to have issues with the code and the sorting process.

```
    int que1count = 0;
    int que2count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (que1.size() + que2.size()); ++i) {
        if(que2.at(que2count) > que1.at(que1count)){
            queMerge.push_back(que2.at(que2count));
            que2count++;
        }
        else{
            queMerge.push_back(que1.at(que1count));
            que1count++;
        }
    }
```

Everything else from here on out works just fine.

```
    cout << "que1: " << que1.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < que1.size(); ++i) {
        cout << que1[i] << endl;
    }
/*
 * The for loop iterates through the first queue and prints out the values indicated at i until the size of the
 * queue is reached
 */

    cout << endl;

    cout << "que2: " << que2.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < que2.size(); ++i) {
        cout << que2[i] << endl;
    }
/*
 * The for loop iterates through the second queue and prints out the values indicated at i until the size of the
 * queue is reached
 */

    cout << endl;

    cout << "queMerge: " << queMerge.size() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < queMerge.size(); ++i) {
        cout << queMerge[i] << endl;
    }
/*
 * The for loop iterates through the queMerge and prints out the values indicated at i until the size of the
 * queue is reached having already been sorted alphabetically earlier in the program
 */

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more precise than "start to have issues"?

Comment: There is an issue with an out of range vector

Comment: in your merge loop, `que1count` and `que2count` can exceed the length of their vectors

Comment: May I suggest drawing out your solution on paper and stepping through your code. I am sure you will find that the block where you are having problems doesn't do anything close to what you intended.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the merge loop?

Comment: You've been invited to debug your code, and have apparently declined. As such I must vote to close. We require a [MCVE] and evidence of research effort.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the out-of-range error, simply change the for loop to the one below to make sure that `que1count` and `que2count` never goes above their string sizes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (que1.size() + que2.size()) && que2count < que2.size() && que1count < que1.size(); ++i)
```

Now this will compile. However, your merge loop still doesn't do what you intend it to. Try using some vector functionalities for `que1` and `que2` too. You're only using vector functionalities for `queMerge` right now.

This can be helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/98971/